# Connection refused error - AWS EC2 ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am getting connection refused error for API request (curl 'http://machineip:5000/User/Authenticate') but i am getting proper response with curl 'http://localhost:5000/User/Authenticate'.

Security Group :-

[image]

and port status on machine:-

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using public ip of the instance, not its private ip?

Comment: yes i am using public ip.

Comment: when you disable the `ufw` does it work?

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: is it dot application? if yes did you set `"server.urls": "http://::5000;http://0.0.0.0:5000"`? or you can try with `dotnet.exe run --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: yes it's dotnet core application.

Comment: okay then try to start application like `dotnet.exe run --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000` seems like its bind with localhost

Comment: "Operational": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    } 
@Adiii still getting same error

Comment: is the instance in public subnet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216992/discussion-between-adiii-and-arvind-kumar).